# Increase allocated memory of a filesystem AIX6.0

Tags: unix, filesystems, db2, aix

I have a filesystem /ABC mounted on /home. I have checked that 90% of it is utilized as per the df -k command.I want to increase the allocated space of the filesystem /ABC .Is (chfs -a size=+20M /ABC) the right command to fire. I am new to AIX kindly help. Currently I am using AIX version 6.0

Comment: Why did you tagged as DB2?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, [chfs](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_aix_71/com.ibm.aix.cmds1/chfs.htm) is the command to modify filesystem parameters.  You'll need to be root to update a filesystem's size.

use the `-a size` option with `=` to set the new size (absolute), or `=+` to increase by a relative amount.

```
chfs -a size=+20M /ABC
```

Note: 
When you say "filesystem /ABC mounted on /home", I would expect that to be /home/ABC, but perhaps you're mistaken.